# Include vs Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models

- User - has many debits and has many credits
- Debit - belongs to User
- Credit - belongs to User

Debit and credit are very similar. The fields are basically the same. 
I'm trying to run a query on my models to return all fields from debit and credit where user is current_user

```
User.left_outer_joins(:debits, :credits).where("users.id = ?", @user.id)
```

As expected returned all fields from User as many times as there were records in credits and debits.

```
User.includes(:credits, :debits).order(created_at: :asc).where("users.id = ?", @user.id)
```

It ran 3 queries and I thought it should be done in one.

The second part of this question is. How I could I add the record type into the query?

as in records from credits would have an extra field to show credits and same for debits

I have looked into ActiveRecordUnion gem but I did not see how it would solve the problem here

Comment: Actually now that I think about it. It would make more sense if credit and debit where one model with a type in it. Also I see that running one query would not work because even though the columns are the same in the query they would need to be specified as debit.colum1, debit.colum2, debit.colum3, credit.colum1, credit.colum2, credit.colum3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`includes` can't magically retrieve everything you want it to in one query; it will run one query per model (typically) that you need to hit. Instead, it eliminates **future** unnecessary queries. Take the following examples:

#### Bad

```
users = User.first(5)
users.each do |user|
  p user.debits.first
end
```

There will be 6 queries in total here, one to User retrieving all the users, then one for each `.debits` call in the loop.

#### Good!

```
users = User.includes(:debits).first(5)
users.each do |user|
  p user.debits.first
end
```

You'll only make two queries here: one for the users and one for their associated debits. This is how `includes` speeds up your application, by eagerly loading things you know you'll need.

As for your comment, yes it seems to make sense to combine them into one table. Depending on your situation, I'd recommend looking into Single Table Inheritance (STI). If you don't go this route, be careful with adding a column called `type`, Rails won't like that!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in the first query, by calling the query on User class you are asking for records of type User and if you do not want user objects you are performing an extra join which could be costly. (COULD BE not will be)

If you want credit and debit records simply call queries on Credit and Debit models. If you load user object somewhere prior to this point, use `includes` `preload` `eager_load` to do load linked credit and debit record all at once.

There is two way of pre-loading records in Rails. In the first, Rails performs single query of each type of record and the second one Rails perform only a one query and load objects of different types using the data returned.
`includes` is a smart pre-loader that performs either one of the ways depending on which one it thinks would be faster.

If you want to force Rails to use one query no matter what, `eager_load` is what you are looking for.

Please read all about `includes`, `eager_load` and `preload` in the article [here](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes).